# Problem in making algebraic substitution in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, differential-equations

I have an equation y'= Ay - By^2 to transform into a linear form
Therefore, i want to substitute y to 1/u.

My code is:

```
y'[x] = A*y[x] - B*y[x]^2

Simplify[y'[x] = A*y[x] - B*y[x]^2, y[x] == 1/u]
```

However, i have the wrong result:
-B/u^2 + A/u.   Here it did not use and substitute the y'[x] part. It should be u'[x] = Au[x] - B. What is the problem in my code?

Comment: does ReplacePart instead of an assumption help?...should be `1/u[x]` right?